# Empty value in datagridview combobox dropdown for nullable type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, enums, datagridviewcombobox

I have a nullable enum binding to a combobox cell.  The comboxbox style is set to dropdown.

Since my enum is nullable, I am expecting the Dropdown to have an empty value, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there any built-in way of enforcing this, other than adding a "NULL" value to the enum and keeping track of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows Forms [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have anything like the [WPF TargetNullValue property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), so the only possible way is to handle the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) events:

```
Binding binding = new Binding // ..
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);

binding.Format += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.Value == null)
        eventArgs.Value = "NULL";
    else
        eventArgs.Value = eventArgs.Value.ToString();
}

binding.Parse += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.Value == "NULL")
        eventArgs.Value = null;
    else
        eventArgs.Value = Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), eventArgs.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I ended up adding an event for CellValueChanged and setting null for the various columns where the NULL enum value was set. This was the easiest approach for my scenario. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I just glanced over the fact that it is not the ComboBox but DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Comment: No worries! Your answer is good enough to point me in the right direction. Besides, if every answer was perfect, how could we ever be perfect? ;)

Comment: No one is perfect :) - that's true. Also, you may add your own answer that actually solves the issue and mark it as accepted - that will be more useful for future users of SO than this answer that only points in the right direction.

Comment: It's fine, I think programmers should be able to figure out the answer from your answer and my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use DBNull.Value in the DataSource:

```
    var col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    col.DataSource = new Object[] { DBNull.Value, MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value2  };
```